# Converting word vectors (from fastText) to use in spaCy fails

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I generated word vectors with fastText and wanted to convert them to use in a spaCy model (for German). In the spaCy documentation it says that the vectors "Should be a tab-separated file in Word2Vec format where the first column contains the word and the remaining columns the values." So, I converted my word vectors so that they have exactly that format, into a txt file. However, when I try to run
`python -m spacy init-model de /Users/vectors --vectors-loc test_vectors.txt`,
I get the following ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ich'

Doesn't my file have the right format? Am I missing out on something?

---

Operating System: Windows 8.1
Python Version Used: 3.6.4
spaCy Version Used: 2.0.11
Environment Information: windows cmd

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded a fasttext model (wiki.el.vec) from fastText [pretrained vectors](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md) and then used the following gensim code to convert them to txt format:

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('wiki.el.vec', binary=False)
model.save_word2vec_format('wiki.el.txt', binary=False)
```

Then I run:

```
python3 -m spacy init-model el . --vectors-loc wiki.el.txt
```

And it worked fine.

Replace el with de and the initial wiki.el.vec file with a corresponding de.vec file and reproduce the steps I followed and I think it will get done.

Hope it helps!