# Load word vectors from Gensim to SpaCy Vectors class

Tags: python, gensim, spacy

As the title says, I would like to load custom word vectors built from `gensim` to the `SpaCy` Vector class.

I have found several other questions where folks have successfully loaded vectors to the `nlp` object itself, but I have a current project where I would like to have a separate Vectors object.

Specifically, I am using BioWordVec to generate my word vectors which serializes the vectors using methods from `gensim.models.Fastext`.

On the `gensim` end I am:

- calling `model.wv.save_word2vec_format(output/bin/path, binary=True)`
- saving the model -> `model.save(path/to/model)`

On the `SpaCy` side:

- I can either use the `from_disk` or `from_bytes` methods to load the word vectors
- there is also a `from_glove` method that expects a vocab.txt file and a binary file (which I already have a binary file

Link to [Vectors Documentation](https://spacy.io/api/vectors)

just for reference, here is my code to test the load process:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.vectors import Vectors 

vecs = Vectors()
path = '/home/medmison690/pyprojects/BioWordVec/pubmed_mesh_test.bin'
dir_path = '/home/medmison690/Desktop/tuned_vecs'


vecs.from_disk(dir_path)


print(vecs.shape)
```

I have tried various combinations of `from_disk` and `from_bytes` with no success. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included this. Not getting an error - just getting a vectors.shape of (0,0)

Comment: Hi, do you know how to loaded "bio_embedding_extrinsic" please?

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate the Spacy docs don't clearly state what formats are used by its various reading functions, nor implement an import that's clearly based on the format written by the original Google `word2vec.c` code.

It seems the `from_disk` expects things in Spacy's own multi-file format. The `from_bytes` might expect a raw version of the vectors. Neither would be useful for data saved from `gensim`'s `FastText` model.

The `from_glove` might in fact be a compatible format. You could try using the `save_word2vec_format()` method with its optional `fvocab` argument (to specify a `vocab.txt` file with words), `binary=True`, and a filename according to Spacy's conventions. For example, if you have 300 dimensional vectors:

```py
ft_model.wv.save_word2vec_format('vectors.300.f.bin', fvocab='vocab.txt', binary=True)
```

Then, see if that directory works for Spacy's `from_glove`. (I'm not sure it will.)

Alternatively, you could possibly use a `gensim` utility class (such as its `KeyedVectors`) to load the vectors into memory, then manually add each vector, one-by-one, into a pre-allocated Spacy `Vectors` object.

Note that by saving FastText vectors to the plain, vectors-only `word2vec_format`, you'll be losing anything the model learned about subwords (which is what FastText-capable models use to synthesize vectors for out-of-vocabulary words).

Comment: Thanks! I actually currently found a working solution following this answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51736080/converting-word-vectors-from-fasttext-to-use-in-spacy-fails) though I am interested to give your method a try. Could you elaborate a bit more on "Note that by saving FastText vectors to the plain, vectors-only word2vec_format".  Is this format other than the binary format?

Comment: Glad you've got something working! Using any of the `save_word2vec_format()` methods just saves a mapping of full-words to vectors (whether `binary` enabled or not). A full FastText model is richer, and learns vecs for subwords, & can thus synthesize vectors for OOV ("out of vocabulary") words it never saw during training, using word fragments. Such vectors aren't great, but they're often better than nothing, given that OOV words may share word-roots with, or be typos of, trained words.

Comment: I've not seen any evidence Spacy can use a full FastText model with subword info, so there may be no direct way to port this benefit of FastText – perhaps the main benefit of FastText over plain Word2Vec – into Spacy. (You could, conceivably, keep the full FT model around, and for words without vectors in the Spacy Vectors object, ask the full FT model – and maybe, if the words are important, copy the synthesized OOV vector into the Spacy `Vectors`.)

Comment: Thanks @gojomo. Getting ready to retrain my embeddings using a larger corpus as the sample data I originally used led to poor performance :)